# Adding statement timeout in connection string doesn't work

Tags: java, connection-timeout, r2dbc

I want add statement timeout in connection string.

I had tried different options by adding statement_timeout parameter:

`r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema?options=statement_timeout=1`
`r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema?options=-c%20statement_timeout=1`
`r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema?options=statement_timeout=1s`
`r2dbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/schema?options=-c%20statement_timeout=1s`

and tried test this by adding in sql file:
`pg_sleep(9999)`

but timeout doesn't work

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: @user207421 -  actually reading the doc seems a bit radical.

Comment: @user207421 thanks for the advice, but i didn't find it in the documentation

Comment: If my answer does not solve your question, please improve your question by stating clearly what you want to know.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql - search "timeout" in that page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the Java guy, but it seems you can set the statement timeout in r2dbc using a map of Options. [Check here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql), and search for Programmatic Connection Factory Discovery.

Also, it seems you can set the parameter at the connection string by using statementTimeout instead of statement_timeout (need to test). I think postgres doesn't support by default setting the statement timeout at the connection string :(

I hope this helps, and please, don't let yourself be discouraged by some people that answered you before. We can always read the docs, for sure, but those people like to keep saying "just read the docs bla bla bla" just to inflate their egos. We can read the docs, but sharing experience and knowledge is also awesome! So, why are these folks wasting their time saying "Read the docs"? Just skip the question.

That's why nowadays people prefer to talk with AI's and StackOverflow is suffering.

Answer (score -1):

To be honest, I agree to the commenters that tell you to read documentation.

After googling "postgresql timeout connection string" you can click [first hit](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html). Then you find the description: "The time to wait (in seconds) while trying to establish a connection before terminating the attempt and generating an error." The default is 15.

This means that it waits for 15 seconds to try and establish a connection. If your device cannot do it, it gives up.
However, if a connection is established, it will live for as long as you don't kill it. At least I think that is what you were expecting?

Comment: I suspect the OP will require more details. Your link is about using PostgreSQL connections in .NET and the OP is specifically using R2DBC and Java.

Comment: OP is trying to set the statement timeout (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT), not the connection timeout.